# Percentage width of H3

Tags: css

this is more of a mathematical question than a programming question, but here goes:

I have a container div that is 100% wide.

Within, I have two floated divs.  The left div is 66% wide and floated left.  The right div is 30% and floated right.

I have an h2 element within the left hand div and I'd like it to extend beyond the constraints of its parent and extend to the far right edge of its parent.

What is the formula to figure out the percentage width of the h2 element, if its parent is 66% of the top container.

I currently, through trial and error, have it set to 151.5%, but I hate that it's just an eyeballed guess.  I'd really like to know how you would figure out the correct percentage.

Since it is a responsive design, I can't use a fixed dimension, it has to be percentage.

Comment: Could you please paste some of your code here so that we can gauge the scope of your layout? (E.g. positioning of divs and what their parents are etc) Try placing your code in a JsFiddle also so that people can have a play around with it.

Comment: Also with this line 'extend to the far right edge of its parent.' do you mean the left hand div's parent element or the left hand div itself?

Comment: I've created a JsFiddle here, but I'm not really looking for advice on how to change the markup or layout.  If I was the developer, I wouldn't be doing this, but I've been asked to adjust the layout without any markup change, so I'm overflowing the h3, which works splendidly, and I'm just wondering *what formula would you use to calculate the percentage of the h3*

http://jsfiddle.net/HGjWJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out.  100% (container width) divided by width of left div (66%) = 151.515152
My mistake was rounding my css percentages to 66% instead of 66.66666667%.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily place your `<h2>` in an absolute position like so

```
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

and then add `position: relative;` to your left column. But this will work well if you only have one  tag in that column. Otherwise you'll need either to do some more math when you're trying to place other `<h2>` elements or use javascript to calculate the width of the bigger container

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but that wasn't what I was asking.  I was asking how to figure out the percentage, not alternative ways of doing this.  I'm heavily restricted on modifying the markup on this particular page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is the solution to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pgJeC/1/

NOTE: Colors are set only to show the layering

```
.id1 {
    width:66%;
    float:left;
    background:maroon;
}
.id2 {
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    background: green;
 }
h3 {
    color:red;
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:block;
}
```